# How to properly overwrite a JQuery function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to overwrite the `date` function in jquery.validate.js

```
// http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Methods/date
date: function (value, element) {
  return this.optional(element) || !/Invalid|NaN/.test(new 
  Date(value).toString());
}
```

in order to handle IE dates and while it's working my local machine I'm getting an error on my test server.

I created a jquery.validate.custom.js where I copied and modified the function assuming it would overwrite it. This is what I have:

```
// http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Methods/date
date: function (value, element) {
  if ($.browser.webkit) {
    //ES - Chrome does not use the locale when new Date objects instantiated:
    var d = new Date();
    return this.optional(element) || !/Invalid|NaN/.test(new Date
           (d.toLocaleDateString(value)));
  }
  else {
     return this.optional(element) || !/Invalid|NaN/.test(new Date(value));
       }
  }
```

But in IE11 on Windows 2012 Server, it throws the following error:

```
JavaScript critical error at line 2, column 16 in 
http://localhost:60306/Scripts/jquery.validate.custom.js\n\nSCRIPT1010: 
Expected identifier
```

When looking at the code, I can clearly see that it highlight the open bracket in:

```
date: function (...
```

and when I move my mouse over it, it displays `Expected identifier`.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: Why down volte and not leave a positive reason as to why it was down voted??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try calling the validator.addMethod method after loading the jquery.validate library as below:

```js
$(function () {
    
    $.validator.addMethod(
        "date",
        function (value, element) {
            var bits = value.match(/([0-9]+)/gi), str;
            if (!bits)
                return this.optional(element) || false;
            str = bits[1] + '/' + bits[0] + '/' + bits[2];
            return this.optional(element) || !/Invalid|NaN/.test(new Date(str));
        },
        "Please enter a date in the format dd/mm/yyyy"
    );
});
```

Comment: I've tried what you suggested and the error is definitely gone and my date is formatted correctly but I can't see where you specify the mask?

Comment: You mean overwriting by masking?

Comment: No, I see that my date is formatted with dd/mm/yyyy and so is your error message but where is that actually defined that it should use this format rather than mm/dd/yyyy for example.

Comment: It is defined as bits. matches with the regex defined in value.match

Answer (score 0):

The answer by @Mervan-Agency should work, as far as I can see (I've upvoted it without actually testing), but I think you could also just do this:

```
$.validator.methods.date = function (value, element) {
  if ($.browser.webkit) {
    //ES - Chrome does not use the locale when new Date objects instantiated:
    var d = new Date();
    return this.optional(element) || !/Invalid|NaN/.test(new Date
           (d.toLocaleDateString(value)));
  } else {
     return this.optional(element) || !/Invalid|NaN/.test(new Date(value));
  }
}
```

The problem with your code is that you've copied and pasted a segment of JSON, which is not valid outside the original context.

Comment: I tried your snippet as well, but it's throwing an error that it doesn't know the methods "Unable to get property 'methods' of undefined or null reference".

Comment: `$.fn.validator.methods.date` ... might work. But you've fixed your problem now, by the look of it.